# FindBugs Eclipse plugin: is there a way to set "Run automatically," and "(also on full build)" options on workspace level?

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

I have an eclipse (kepler) workspace with several (mostly java) projects. I just installed the FindBugs (2.0.3) plugin, and noticed that the *"Run automatically,"* and *"(also on full build)"* options are only configurable on the project level - and not on the workspace level.

Is there any convenient way to enable/disable these options on the workspace level (other than a search/replace approach on all .project files)?

**UPDATE**: it seems this feature is considered to be added to the upcoming 3.0.1 version:

https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/feature-requests/287/

This may also mean that there's no way to do this in the 2.0.3 plugin, which means the solution to this problem is to write a search&replace script :-(

Comment: How exactly do you do that search&replace?

Comment: @Rafaesp Take a look at my own answer, workaround 2. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: since this question received no answers in about a year, it is safe to assume, that the answer is: **no**, the Eclipse Find Bugs plugin 2.0.3 (or earlier) is not capable of the workspace-level configuration of the mentioned options.

Possible workarounds:

1. Upgrade to 3.x.x or higher versions of the plugin. (I already mentioned that in the question above.)
2. If upgrading is not an option, you have to bulk update your .project
   files. Now I'm pretty sure there's an XML tool or a nice scripting
   language, that is designed for this kind of problem (bulk
   update of XML content). But since I already had to solve this exact
   problem [with a simple Java program, I might as well recommend just
   that](https://gitlab.com/acsipak/ProjectXmlFixer).